# Configure JDBC driver in JBoss 7 - as a deployment OR as a module?

Tags: deployment, module, datasource, jboss7.x, configure

As mentioned in the article https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7 JBoss 7 provides 2 main ways to configure a data source.

What is the **BEST** practice of configuring a data source in JBoss 7 AS ? Is it

1. As a module?
2. As a deployment?

(The same question has been asked in the thread https://community.jboss.org/thread/198023, but no one has provided an acceptable answer yet.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guide [JBoss AS7 DS configuration](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7) says the recommended way is to configure the datasource by deployment

But according to discussion on the link [Jboss 7 DS configuration JBoss Community Discussion](https://community.jboss.org/thread/198023) on page 54 of the guide it mentions that the recommended way to deploy JDBC driver is to use modular approach

But I personally say that the better(not the best) approach to configure JDBC driver would be to use modules because of 3 reasons

1. JDBC driver will generally not change.
2. Re-usability : You can use the same module across various applications and not deploy the jar along with each application, this prevents duplicacy
3. Space Effective : Using the module approach lets you reduce the size of your EAR/WAR as you do not need to supply the jar with the package

Hence I would argue that the better of the two approaches is via modules

Comment: Thanks for the response. Most of articles has some justification for the reason 2.

Answer (score 0):

@Mukul Goel 
It's not necessary to include it the EAR of your application it's sufficient to put the .jar inside the deployments folder so:

no need to embed in ear
no need to create a module

Jist deploy in deployments folder or via admin console

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, I also agree with what Mukul has suggested, as a best practice. This is really, systematic approach in case of projects with higher complexities.

Comment: I don't agree because I like the idea to just download an application server and deploy my war. It's annoying to modify something in the JBoss/Wildfly directories first.