# What's the module name if deploy jdbc in Jboss AS 7 as web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, jboss, ejb

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414426/configure-jdbc-driver-in-jboss-7-as-a-deployment-or-as-a-module) start from Jboss AS7 the jdbc driver is able to deploy as regular application. However a question is, how other application is able to refer to this jdbc jar?

here is what I tried but it doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
......
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="ojdbc6.jar" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
.....
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

### UPDATE

When I deploy ojdbc.jar there is a section of log from console:

```
10:56:20,416 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ojdbc6.jar"
10:56:21,487 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
10:56:21,489 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011907: Register module: Module "deployment.ojdbc6.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
10:56:21,499 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 6) JBAS018559: Deployed "ojdbc6.jar"
```

Per the log jdbc module is with name `deployment.ojdbc6.jar:main`, but after I update jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
......
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="deployment.ojdbc6.jar:main" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
.....
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

it still does not work. with following message:

```
10:59:34,448 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 7) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "MyApp.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApp.war.war\".POST_MODULE Missing[JBAS014861: <one or more transitive dependencies>]","jboss.module.service.\"deployment.MyApp.war.war\".main Missing[jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.ojdbc6.jar:main\".main]"]}
10:59:35,198 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment MyApp.war.war in 749ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the jars from other deployments in this way:

```
  <module name="deployment.YourEarOrWar.YourJar.jar" />
```

Where deployment is the general prefix for a reference to your deployed apps.
However, for a lib like a jdbc-driver I recommend to put it in the module-folder of the JBoss

```
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="driver.ojdbc">

<resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>      
</resources>

 </module>
```

and reference it then

```
  <module name="driver.ojdbc"/>
```

See also
https://community.jboss.org/thread/169894
and
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7

Comment: Thanks. I tried your advice and update the original post. It still doesn't work, did I miss something in the configuration?

Comment: Forget to mention your explanation and links are very helpful.

Comment: You are right! it works, module name should simply be `<module name="deployment.ojdbc.jar" />`