# Registering driver : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource

Tags: java, jboss, driver, h2

I need to have H2 in the classpath. I'm using these values :

```
# driver=org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource # it doesn't work
driver=org.h2.Driver                 # it doesnt work too...
url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/mydb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
login=sa
password=
```

And I have declared datasource in my `standalone.xml` :

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mydb" pool-name="mydb" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
      <connection-url>jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/mydb</connection-url>
      <driver>h2</driver>
      <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
      </security>
<datasource>
<drivers>
      <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
          <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
      </driver>
</drivers>
```

And I have the default `module.xml` for H2 in JBoss A7.

But when registering the JDBC using this :
Class.forName(driver);

I get this exception :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
```

And the same for the other value :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver
```

Please can you help me get the solution?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Add the corresponding driver jar file to classpath?

Answer (score 0):

There is normally no need to register the driver, if your (web) application runs in an application server context. You just use the data source. The application server registers the driver for you, and that's why the driver's class is not necessarily visible to your application.

As for JBoss 7, the H2 driver is provided as a module. So if you really need to register it, you could declare a module dependency (in an .ear or in a .war deployment) by adding a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.

References (regarding to module dependencies):

- [What's the module name if deploy jdbc in Jboss AS 7 as web application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18478811/2390083)
- [Add an Explicit Module Dependency to a Deployment](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Add_an_Explicit_Module_Dependency_to_a_Deployment1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and fixed when added this dependency in maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.199</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34203570/2593751)