# Whats the correct way to allow different jdbc drivers for deployed applications on JBoss / Wildfly?

Tags: jdbc, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

My setting is the following:

- I got an application, which I deploy in `/standalone/deployments`
- The `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` of my deployment in `/standalone/deployments` looks the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            [...]
            <module name="org.postgresql"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

- To drop the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` completely (because it must not be used if there are no classloading issues), doesn't work. I use more dependencies (keycloak) beside the driver, which can't be found then.
- My `module.xml` in my module `org/postgresql/main` looks like this (like described in https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_installation/index.html#package-the-jdbc-driver)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name="org.postgresql" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-42.2.5.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

- My requirement is, to allow different types of jdbc-drivers, e.g. postgres, oracle, mssql.

---

**First option:**

I can change my `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            [...]
            <module name="org.postgresql" optional="TRUE"/>
            <module name="com.oracle.ojdbc6" optional="TRUE"/>
            [...]
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

(added the optional-parameter)

Then I have to allow all drivers explicitly. Seems to be not the best way.

The idea comes from the standard [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/development_guide/class_loading_and_modules).

---

**Second option:**

I change my module-path to `driver/jdbc/main` (instead of `org/postgres/main`)  and the `module.xml` to

```xml
<module name="driver.jdbc" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5">
[...]
</module>
```

(changed name of module)

and go with the module-reference in my `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` like

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    [...]
    <module name="driver.jdbc"/>
    [...]
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Now I force my customers to name the driver-module like I proposed. They can't name the module like mentioned in every standard-documentation.

The idea comes from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478811/whats-the-module-name-if-deploy-jdbc-in-jboss-as-7-as-web-application).

---

I am doing this in context of a keycloak installation with a self-implemented User-federation to access a separate (legacy) user-database. Therefore dropping the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` is no option as mentioned above.

**Whats the correct way to achieve my goal of being flexible with the jdbc-driver?**

---

**EDIT:** mentioned, dropping `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I went with a hybrid solution of my two above mentioned approaches for the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` like as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.postgresql" optional="TRUE"/>
            <module name="com.oracle.ojdbc6" optional="TRUE"/>
            [...]
            <module name="driver.jdbc" optional="TRUE"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I listed all the relevant database divers as optional modules and listed another one with flexible naming if a driver is desired, which is not mentioned in the list above.

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak have a very well designed container. You can get inspiration from it for your deployment. Just take a look at how the [Dockerfile installs database driver modules](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/d36dcd796aa4f3a75cea3a3e48ec77b95e11e4e2/server/tools/build-keycloak.sh#L50) and later [how to activate those modules using jboss_cli](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/d36dcd796aa4f3a75cea3a3e48ec77b95e11e4e2/server/tools/cli/databases/postgres/change-database.cli#L9).

Of course, if you can, maybe you can use the container instead. Just make sure to include the module.xml for your driver and activate it on start-up by providing your own entrypoint.

Comment: I'm quite sure, that my ex-colleagues solved the issue from above (or faced it completely different) using docker. :) But good hint.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should install all database drivers individually as modules. Individual modules will help you to track and upgrade driver jars easily in the future.

As long as you don't have any classloading problems with your application you don't need to mention these drivers in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file. They are *static modules* and will be loaded on server startup.

Moreover, after installing the driver modules, you have to add entries in the standalone.xml file. For example, if I have installed Oracle driver then

```
<driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
 <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

within the  tag.
Add a datasource definition within the  tag (next to ExampleDS):

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/[NAME]" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true">
 <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@[HOST_NAME]:1521:[SID]</connection-url>
  <driver>oracle[has to match the driver name]</driver>
  <pool>
   <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
   <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
   <prefill>true</prefill>
  </pool>
  <security>
   <user-name>[USER]</user-name>
   <password>[PWD]</password>
  </security>
</datasource>
```

Comment: I don't want to install all drivers on one system but a different driver on each customer-system. If i don't mention the driver in the jboss-deployment-structure, I get an error with "no suitable driver found".

Comment: Or was your approach to remove the jboss-deployment-structure completely? The part with standalone.xml is understood and done.

Comment: What I am trying to say is don't use `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` if you don't have any class loading issues. Wildfly will load the configuration from the standalone.xml file in which you have mentioned the module details under the `driver` tag.

Comment: To drop the ``jboss-deployment-structure.xml`` completely doesn't work. I use more dependencies beside the driver, which can't be found then. Error: ``java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [...] org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/mappers/OIDCAccessTokenMapper.``
After removing only the drivers I also get: ``java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://myUrl``. So, for me it seems, that I can't drop the ``jboss-deployment-structure.xml`` or the drivers within the file.